# Meteor Kendo UI kendoGrid not working

Tags: meteor, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm trying to render a collection in a kendoGrid with multiple column sorting.

The code is in http://meteorpad.com/pad/PceRM6RYE6aKFAcTh/Copy%20of%20Leaderboard
I modified the example provided by Kendo UI, but the grid is not being displayed.

Can anyone please help me to make this work?

Comment: It is definitely throwing an error: "Exception from Tracker afterFlush function:"
"TypeError: this.$(...).kendoGrid is not a function" And according to the Kendo documentation this is an known issue with jQuery is not properly added, though I don't see any particular issue with this from the source.

Comment: Hi Tim C, it seems that kendoGrid is only available in the PRO version so it shouldn't be included in the free version kendo-ui core :/

Comment: You may want to add to the question the error that you are receiving and then answer your own question with this information about the PRO version! I have noticed a number of people around the net asking this and it may come in handy in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The error in the console says: "TypeError: this.$(...).kendoGrid is not a function"

This occurs because kendoGrid is included only in kendo-ui PRO Version and not in kendo-ui core.